# Specifying default filenames with argparse, but not opening them on --help?

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have a script that does some work on a file. It takes this file's name on the command line, but if it's not provided, it defaults to a known filename (`content.txt`, say). With python's `argparse`, I use the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my illustrative example')
parser.add_argument('--content', metavar='file', 
                     default='content.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                     help='file to process (defaults to content.txt)')
args = parser.parse_args()
# do some work on args.content, which is a file-like object
```

This works great. The only problem is that if I run `python myscript --help`, I get an `ArgumentError` if the file isn't there (which I guess makes sense), and the help text is not shown. I'd rather it not try to open the file if the user just wants `--help`. Is there any way to do this? I know I could make the argument a string and take care of opening the file myself later (and I've been doing that), but it would be convenient to have `argparse` take care of it.

Comment: Well, it looks like you'll have to make a decision here. You can either make the default file available (by virtue of it being a 'default') or just open the file yourself, as you've suggested yourself. Alternatively, it looks like you can use stdin as a default, however you won't be able to specify a default file name, which might not be a bad option if you don't want to populate that file.

Comment: FWIW this is apparently fixed in a new enough Python version, the snippet you provided works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the argparse code, I see:

- `ArgumentParser.parse_args` calls `parse_known_args` and makes sure that there isn't any pending argument to be parsed.
- `ArgumentParser.parse_known_args` sets default values and calls `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args`

Hence, the workaround would be to use `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args` directly to detect `-h` and, after that, use `ArgumentParser.parse_args` as usual.

```
import sys, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my illustrative example', argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--content', metavar='file',
                     default='content.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                     help='file to process (defaults to content.txt)')
parser._parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:], argparse.Namespace())
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Note that `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args` needs a couple of parameters: the arguments from the command line and the namespace.

Of course, I wouldn't recommend this approach since it takes advantage of the internal `argparse` implementation and that might change in the future. However, I don't find it too messy, so you still might want to use it if you think maintenance risks pay off.

Comment: It seems there isn't really a nice solution to this, but this will do for a one-off script. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You could subclass `argparse.FileType`:

```
import argparse
import warnings

class ForgivingFileType(argparse.FileType):
    def __call__(self, string):
        try:
            super(ForgivingFileType,self).__call__(string)
        except IOError as err:
            warnings.warn(err)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my illustrative example')
parser.add_argument('--content', metavar='file', 
                     default='content.txt', type=ForgivingFileType('r'),
                     help='file to process (defaults to content.txt)')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This works without having to touch private methods like `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args`.

Answer (score 2):

Use stdin as default:

```
parser.add_argument('file', default='-', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could define your own [`type`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type) or [`action`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) in the `add_argument` call that checks if the file exists, and returns a file handle if it does and `None` (or something else) otherwise.

This would require you to write some code of yourself as well though, but if the default value can not always be used you probably have to do some checking sooner or later. Like Manny D argues you might want to reconsider your default value.